Next.js - Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/"
I’m encountering a persistent error in my Next.js app:
Internal error: Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/"

Despite trying multiple solutions, the issue remains unresolved. Below are the key details of my setup:

Next.js Version: 14.2.14
React Version: 18.3.1
React-Redux & Tailwind CSS are also part of the project.

The relevant code for my page.js file is as follows:
layout.js:
import './globals.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '@/store/store';

export const metadata = {
  title: "Hall of Game",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Provider store={store}>
          {children}
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

page.js:
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Header from "@/features/Header/Header";
import Filters from "@/features/Filters/Filters";
import GamesList from "@/features/Games/GamesList/GamesList";
import GameDetails from "@/features/Games/GameDetails/GameDetails";
import { selectCurrentGame } from "@/features/Games/gamesSlice";

const Home = () => {
  const selectedGame = useSelector(selectCurrentGame);
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <section>
          <Filters />
        </section>
        <section>
          {selectedGame ? <GameDetails game={selectedGame}/> : <GamesList />}
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

Steps I’ve already taken:

Checked for default export issues – export default Home is present at the bottom of the file.
Cleared cache & rebuilt the app – I tried npm run dev and next build after clearing the cache and reinstalling node_modules.
Verified file path – The page.js file is located at src/app/page.js.
Tried solutions from forums – Including resetting and reinstalling React dependencies.

Observations:

The error initially wasn’t present with the default layout.js & page.js files that were provided from the create-next-app set up, and the app rendered fine with this. However, after some recent changes (installing or updating dependencies), this error started occurring.
I’ve reviewed the Next.js documentation and common mistakes article, but I haven’t found a fix.

My package.json:
{
  "name": "hall-of-game",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "next": "^14.2.14",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.25.7",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.14",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  }
}

Any advice or additional steps would be greatly appreciated!

You're using a named export for your RootLayout instead of a default export. I have just updated your RootLayout component and I believe that should fix your error.
import './globals.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '@/store/store';

export const metadata = {
  title: "Hall of Game",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout ({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Provider store={store}>
          {children}
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


This returned a failed to compile build error because you cannot use export default & const together in a single line like that.
export default function RootLayout returned:
Error: This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component.
Thanks for taking the time to look at it though. Any suggestion is welcome as I feel like I've tried everything.

You may try this way. Feel free to ask if you have any problem.
const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (<> {// Put your HTML} </>);
};
    
export default RootLayout;

